# Sharing file in windows xp (sp3) to other computers in the workgroup

Tags: workgroup, windows-xp, network-shares, passwords

Right, I know it sounds easy, and it's likely to have an easy answer but here's my scenario:

I have a computer at the office running windows xp with the service pack 3, and my boss asked me to share some files in the network so that him and another computer can access a certain folder in my computer and modify/add/delete files.

That part was easy, but he then asked for a password protected shared folder on my computer that I don't have access to (Must point out that the computer I'm talking about is directly connected by Ethernet and it's not a laptop) that they can also modify files inside of but that I don't have access to.

Well, here's where I fail. My approach (since I couldn't find an out-of-the-box feature in WinXp) was to place a password protected zip folder inside the shared folder so, even though I could see it, I didn't know the password (When I say ME in this context, means anyone using this computer) and they could edit the zipped folder.

But it all went wrong, and in the end, while I was able to see the shared files, and access the password protected one introducing the password I wasn't able to modify anything at all.

I had simple file sharing deactivated if that's relevant.
Wow this is longer that I expected. Thanks for reading, and double thanks if you're able to point me in the right direction.

:)

Comment: To make that work, the folder you can't access has to be shared from a different user, who is an administrator.
Also, if your login has admin rights, there is really no way short of encryption to keep you out of it, as you can just reset the permissions.

Comment: So basically if I share something as an Admin on my computer, I wouldn't be able to access it from the workgroup on that same computer either?

What about the other users, will it be password protected?